# Windows Authentication is not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, ntlm

In my MVC5 application Windows Authentication is not working. 
When the application is opened in IE it is prompting for credentials each and every time (after clearing temp data, cache, cookies) when the application is accessed.

In IIS, below configurations are done,

1. Windows Authentication Enabled
2. Anonymous Authentication Disabled
3. Under Authentication -> Windows Authentication -> NTLM alone enabled.

In Web.config

```
<location path="Home">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*" />
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
```

Now the actual issue is, Chrome not at all asking for credentials when the application is accessed

Comment: remove <deny users="*" /> ,here * means all users.

Comment: @SagarR, I agree, even if that the case it should prompt for credentials right?? But chrome is not at all prompting for credentials

Comment: ok. this link might be useful - >http://www.lansweeper.com/kb/141/enabling-or-disabling-login-prompts.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some analysis, I found there are some `chrome.exe` running in background. After killing the task `Windows Authentication` works in `Chrome`.